# Drupal 8 upload and embed a video to WYSIWYG

Tags: files

So what I am searching for is a module that gives us the exactly same functionality that we already have with the image tool in Drupal 8 in the WYSIWYG editor.
And that should be working with just uploaded videos.
I found that this module should be doing it for D7 - https://www.drupal.org/project/video

And also this module https://www.drupal.org/project/video_embed_field is doing it for D8, but only for videos from per say YouTube, Vimeo etc.

So please let me know if you found a way to add a similar to the image (see  attached screenshot) but for video

[image]

Cheers and thanks in advance!

Comment: You can achieve this with mix of media modules. Here are some resources you can look  http://flocondetoile.fr/blog/managing-media-drupal-8      http://www.annertech.com/blog/reusable-media-drupal-8-tutorial?utm_source=The+Weekly+Drop&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=The_Weekly_Drop_Issue_245_06_23_2016

Comment: On top of that you may need `Embed` and `entity embed` modules

Answer (score 1):

For simple solution Just get `video_embed_field` which includes module  `Video Embed WYSIWYG` Enable both of them. You will get options to configure your WYSIWYG here `admin/config/content/formats/manage/full_html`. Just add the Video button in toolbar and checked the option `Video Embed WYSIWYG`. I hope you get what you want.
Thanks